# How can I combine the below if loops?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

I want to combine below two for loops and corresponding if-loops with break statement. How can I do that.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            if(i==2){
                System.out.println("i2: "+ i);
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("i2: "+ i);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            if(i==4){
                System.out.println("i4: "+ i);
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("i4: "+ i);
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Firstly, what is *this* code supposed to do?

Comment: please explain the requirements well.

Comment: Remove the `break`s, store the values in variables.

Comment: Is this a homework exercise?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     public class Test {

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                boolean 2completed = false;
                boolean 4completed = false;

                for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                    if(i==2){
                        System.out.println("i2: "+ i);
                        2completed = true;
                    }

                    else if(i==4){
                        System.out.println("i4: "+ i);
                        4completed = true
                    }

                    if(!2completed)
                          System.out.println("i2: "+ i);

                    if(!4completed)
                        System.out.println("i4: "+ i);
                }
            }


            }
```